# Can't figure out why I am getting strange output

Tags: c, function

I'm pretty novice. I've been working through the K&R C programming book, and one of the exercises was to write a program that prints any input lines that are longer than 80. Here's my code:

```
include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getaline(char line[], int maxline);

int main()
{
    int i, c;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    if ((c = getaline(line, MAXLINE)) > 80){
            for (i =0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)
                    if (c != '\0')
                            printf("%c", line[i]);
            printf("\n");
    }
}
/* reads a line into S, returns the length of that line */
int getaline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
            s[i] = c;
            ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

So I'll pipe a line longer than 80 chars to the compiled program. Here's the output:

cat input.txt | ./a.out

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
??i?F???4?w??>&Y?_???xf?7U?h@?
??i??7U?v??i??7U??7U?(?7U?@?
H??i?8?7U??7U?

It prints the line, but it gives all this anomalous output. I tried to figure out why, but I just can't seem to find why.

However, I am pretty sure that the problem lies in the getaline function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: you continue to print characters in line after you encounter `'\0'`

Comment: no. You just skip the print for `'\0'` The for will go on

Comment: `i < MAXLINE` --> `i < c` , `if (line[i] != '\0')`

Comment: No, because you did not fill the line with 0 before calling getaline(). You read some characters from the terminal, and then there is lots of garbage in the rest of the line, which you happily print unless it's 0.

Comment: @HansKlünder Read `getaline()` - the line is always 0-terminated after reading. That's not the problem.

Comment: You are right, that's not the problem. The problem ist that he prints all the characters that follow the null-termination. He does not check if a characters is 0. He checks if c is 0, and it isn't.

Comment: `for (i=0; line[i]; ++i) printf("%c", line[i]);`

Comment: The answer that someone gave fixed the problem. I was treating c as if it were a character, when it was the number that getaline had returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `c` with the current character.

Try this, change this

```
for (i =0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)
```

with

```
for (i = 0 ; i < c ; ++i)
```

and the check should be

```
if (line[i] != '\0')
```

instead of

```
if (c != '\0')
```

your `getaline()` function returns, `i` the position of the last character read, you are comparing it with the null termination byte.

Also if you are null terminating the string, why don't you just

```
printf("%s\n", line);
```

this code should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getaline(char line[], int maxline);

int main()
{
    int i, c;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    if ((c = getaline(line, MAXLINE)) > 80)
        printf("%s\n", line);

    return 0; // you must return from main()
}
/* reads a line into S, returns the length of that line */
int getaline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0 ; (i < lim - 1) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n') ; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') 
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Haha. My bad. Forgot to accept it. This is my first post on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `c` as though it were a character, when it's the line-length count; it will never be equal to `\0`, so you keep pringting.

```
if ((c = getaline(line, MAXLINE)) > 80){

   // c now equals, let's say, 81

        for (i =0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)

                // c is still 81, we never fail

                if (c != '\0')
                        printf("%c", line[i]);
        printf("\n");
}
```

Consider this instead:

```
if (getaline(line, MAXLINE) > 80) {
  for (i =0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)
  {
    c = line[i];

    if (c != '\0')
      printf("%c", c;
    else
      break;
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This has helped. Thank you! I see what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: I think your solution is quite clear. No idea who downvotes that. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
        for (i =0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)
                if (c != '\0')
                        printf("%c", line[i]);
```

by

```
        for (i =0; i < c; ++i)
                        printf("%c", line[i]);
```